# Summing table rows generated with AngularJS by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

It maybe sounds weird but based in the following [table](http://codepen.io/wefs/pen/VmeadW/?editors=1010) I need to sum all rows by using jQuery. I'm using angularjs to list all users but I need to get each row with jQuery and then show the sum of all them.

The only problem is  I don't know how to get the value of each row in order to make the operation.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controllerApp">
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
         <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
             <td>{{user.name}}</td> 
             <td class="sum">{{user.age}}</td>
         </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
         <tr>
              <td><strong>Sum</strong></td>
              <td></td>
         </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
function tally (selector) {
    $(selector).each(function () {
        var total = 0,
            column = $(this).siblings(selector).andSelf().index(this);
        $(this).parents().prevUntil(':has(' + selector + ')').each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($('td.sum:eq(' + column + ')', this).html()) || 0;
        })
        $(this).html(total);
    });
}
tally('td.total');
});
```

**Angularjs**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope){
    $scope.users = [
        {name: "Marie", age: 24},
        {name: "Andy", age: 26},
        {name: "Peter", age: 21},
        {name: "Elizabeth", age: 23},
        {name: "Frank", age: 27},
        {name: "Claire", age: 25}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery or any DOM query to do it... use the javascript controller

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is not to do any modification outside of the angulars scope
Read this: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)

But if you really must access it from outside of angular then this is the correct way to do it:

```
$('table').scope().users.reduce((a,b) => a+b.age, 0)
```

I would do it something more like this:

```
$scope.users = [
    {name: "Marie", age: 24},
    {name: "Andy", age: 26},
    {name: "Peter", age: 21},
    {name: "Elizabeth", age: 23},
    {name: "Frank", age: 27},
    {name: "Claire", age: 25}
]

$scope.totally = $scope.users.reduce((a,b) => a+b.age, 0)
// <td class="total">{{totally}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

After deciding that it's more trouble than it's worth to figure out how to execute jQuery after Angular is finished rendering, the following is my solution using just Angular and [some LoDash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#reduce).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope){
    $scope.users = [
        {name: "Marie", age: 24},
        {name: "Andy", age: 26},
        {name: "Peter", age: 21},
        {name: "Elizabeth", age: 23},
        {name: "Frank", age: 27},
        {name: "Claire", age: 25}
    ];
    $scope.sum = _.reduce($scope.users, function(sum, n) {
      return sum + n.age;
    }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controllerApp">
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
         <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
             <td>{{user.name}}</td> 
             <td class="sum" tally>{{user.age}}</td>
         </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
         <tr>
              <td><strong>Sum</strong></td>
              <td>{{ sum }}</td>
         </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need lodash for just this simple thing... javascript has reduce built in ...in decent browsers

Comment: Yea you're right, you don't "need" it cause javascript has it built in. I wan't aware that javascript has it built in until I saw your answer. In my brain I went "oh that'll need some collection operation, so LoDash!"